# Asp.Net MVC 3 MembershipProvider and ClientCertificate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, client-certificates

I was thinking about writing my own MembershipProvider for my web app. People won't normally register but will be supplied with login info. Will membership then not be the right thing?

I still will have some roles and such as well and I might wan't to be able for people to Authenticate using ClientCertificate instead of normal login. I still wan't them to be membership verified (there is a identifiable field in Certificate and Database I could use) and use roles and such.

Is MembershipProvider perhaps only used with original login Authentication and not authorization?

There doesn't seem to happen anything special when a user is validated so hwo does the authorization atrtibute know who is autorized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing membership works just fine if you want to supply login info. There is *no* requirement that user registration be initiated by the user. Just take the standard code and let the site administrator run it.

Yes, membership is just for authentication. The out of the box feature for authorization is the roles feature.

Comment: So it does not store any info about the user when the membership.validate method is called? How does AutorizeAttribute know whether a user is authorized?

Comment: AuthorizeAttribute just looks at `User.IsAuthenticated`. Membership sets that. It uses public key encryption/signing. Membership decrypts the user's cookie and checks its signature.

Comment: Then there will be a problem with those who Authenticate using ClientCertificate. They will not need a password to validate but still have to be in a membership table. I was thinking about defining a new method into the Membership provider for these people but I don't understand where ValidateUser sets the IsAuthenticated property.

Comment: No, don't reinvent the wheel; this is *hard* to do right even for experts. Consider either a federated identity provider *or* send in your certificate and directly call the usual Membership API to register the user.

Comment: I do belive we're not on the same page. There are pre-defined members that can log in. They can use a username/password or they can use a ClientCertificate. I get a ID from the ClientCertificate I could use to match with a pre-defined member and thus get his userrole and such. I'm just not understanding how, when [Authorize] is set it know when a user is authenticated. You name the User.IsAuthenticated, but where in the validation process is this set so I can set it for those validated by ClientCertificate. Is it the username in the cookie perhaps?